# Como mudar a cor dos botões ao selecionar um input radio?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Tenho esse formulário
[image: Formulário que muda os botões ao selecionar o input radio]

Quando marcar o input radio "Contas a Pagar", preciso que os botões fiquem vermelhos.

Estou usando AngularJS, então usei `ng-if`, mas o código ficou bem extenso.

Como poderia fazer isso de uma forma mais simples?

Comment: coloca o código aqui jsfiddle.net pra gente ver!

Comment: Mostra o seu código para ajudar na análise. Você pode usar também o `ng-class` que é condicional

Comment: Angular oferece muitas regras de validação que podemos usar,ng-minlength, ng-maxlength e vários outros. Confira neste link como fazer a alteração de acordo com o preenchimento de campos no formulário, o mesmo pode ser aplicado na sua situação. http://airtonvancin.com/blog/angularjs-validacao-de-formulario/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não precisa usar `ng-if` nesse caso. Você pode criar uma classe pai para os seus botões dentro. Quando o checkbox for ativado, você usa `ng-class` para adicionar uma classe ao contêiner pai no caso do checkbox desejado ser selecionado.

Assim, isso afetaria os botões.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
```

```css
.container-btn .btn{
  background: green;
  border:none;
  border-radius:4px;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
}

.container-btn.marked .btn{
   background: red;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="a_pagar=false">
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-value="true" ng-model="a_pagar">
            Contas a pagar
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-value="false" ng-model="a_pagar">
            Contas a pagar
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container-btn" ng-class="{'marked' : a_pagar}">
        <button class="btn">Vencidos</button>
        <button class="btn">Hoje</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Observe que a classe `container-btn` afeta o botão que tem a classe `btn`. Caso o checkbox for marcado, a classe 'marked`é adicionada a`container-btn`.

Para você entender melhor, o `ng-class` serve para você adicionar classes dinamicamente pelo Angular. Você precisa definir um `Objeto` com índices contendo uma expressão. Se a expressão for avaliada como verdadeira, o valor do índice será adicionar na classe do elemento.

Você pode ler mais sobre o `ng-class` na [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass);